# How to display data from a local json file in react js.?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, datamapper

Iam trying to get a response from my local json file i have imported the data from the external file and placed it in local json file but when i try to map data in the component it dives me an error that map is not a function and it doesnt works. Also i waant to access an object from the internal array which is UserDataQuestions array and map it in my component

My component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import frontPage from "./dummy";

export default class DummyForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      field: "",
      checkBox: "",
      options: "",
      radioField: "",
      error: "",
      data: frontPage,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: frontPage,
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(frontPage);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        
              {this.state.data.map((x, i) => (
                <select className="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
                  <option key={i}>
                    {x.QuestionText}
                  </option>
                </select>
              ))}
            </React.Fragment>
          }
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

My Json file

```
export default {
  frontPage: [
{
  "Id": "65f22db1-2a6c-4966-8c46-6ea6e02b5df3",
  "UserDataQuestions": [
    {
      "Id": 76,
      "EarnMoreServiceId": "65f22db1-2a6c-4966-8c46-6ea6e02b5df3",
      "QuestionText": "Adresse inkl. postnummer og by",
      "QuestionType": "TextBox",
      "IsProfile": false,
      "IsRequired": false,
      "IsActive": false,
      "RegexExpression": "",
      "RequiredErrorText": "",
      "InvalidErrorText": "",
      "FieldName": "FullAddress",
      "FieldResponse": null,
      "OrderBy": 4,
      "CreatedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "ModifiedOn": null,
      "UserOptions": []
    },
    {
      "Id": 69,
      "EarnMoreServiceId": "65f22db1-2a6c-4966-8c46-6ea6e02b5df3",
      "QuestionText": "Har du hjemmeboende børn?",
      "QuestionType": "Radio",
      "IsProfile": false,
      "IsRequired": false,
      "IsActive": false,
      "RegexExpression": "",
      "RequiredErrorText": "",
      "InvalidErrorText": "",
      "FieldName": "field30",
      "FieldResponse": null,
      "OrderBy": 5,
      "CreatedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "ModifiedOn": null,
      "UserOptions": [
        {
          "Id": 10608,
          "Value": "Ja",
          "Description": "Ja",
          "Type": "field30",
          "IsActive": false,
          "IsSelected": false,
          "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "OrderBy": 1,
          "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 69
        },
        {
          "Id": 10609,
          "Value": "Nej",
          "Description": "Nej",
          "Type": "field30",
          "IsActive": false,
          "IsSelected": false,
          "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "OrderBy": 2,
          "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 69
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 68,
      "EarnMoreServiceId": "65f22db1-2a6c-4966-8c46-6ea6e02b5df3",
      "QuestionText": "Har du børn?",
      "QuestionType": "CheckBox",
      "IsProfile": false,
      "IsRequired": false,
      "IsActive": false,
      "RegexExpression": "",
      "RequiredErrorText": "",
      "InvalidErrorText": "",
      "FieldName": "Q68",
      "FieldResponse": null,
      "OrderBy": 7,
      "CreatedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "ModifiedOn": null,
      "UserOptions": [
        {
          "Id": 10601,
          "Value": "Ingen børn",
          "Description": "Ingen børn",
          "Type": "Q68",
          "IsActive": false,
          "IsSelected": false,
          "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "OrderBy": 1,
          "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
        },
        {
          "Id": 10602,
          "Value": "Ja i alderen 0-3 år",
          "Description": "Ja i alderen 0-3 år",
          "Type": "Q68",
          "IsActive": false,
          "IsSelected": false,
          "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "OrderBy": 2,
          "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
        },
        {
          "Id": 10603,
          "Value": "Ja i alderen 4-6 år",
          "Description": "Ja i alderen 4-6 år",
          "Type": "Q68",
          "IsActive": false,
          "IsSelected": false,
          "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "OrderBy": 3,
          "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
        },
        {
          "Id": 10604,
          "Value": "Ja i alderen 7-9 år",
          "Description": "Ja i alderen 7-9 år",
          "Type": "Q68",
          "IsActive": false,
          "IsSelected": false,
          "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "OrderBy": 4,
          "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
        },
        {
          "Id": 10605,
          "Value": "Ja i alderen 10-13 år",
          "Description": "Ja i alderen 10-13 år",
          "Type": "Q68",
          "IsActive": false,
          "IsSelected": false,
          "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "OrderBy": 5,
          "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
        },
        {
          "Id": 10606,
          "Value": "Ja i alderen 14-18 år",
          "Description": "Ja i alderen 14-18 år",
          "Type": "Q68",
          "IsActive": false,
          "IsSelected": false,
          "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "OrderBy": 6,
          "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
        },
        {
          "Id": 10607,
          "Value": "Ja over 18 år.",
          "Description": "Ja over 18 år.",
          "Type": "Q68",
          "IsActive": false,
          "IsSelected": false,
          "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "OrderBy": 7,
          "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 6,
      "EarnMoreServiceId": "65f22db1-2a6c-4966-8c46-6ea6e02b5df3",
      "QuestionText": "Indkomst (for hele din husstand, i alt pr. år før skat)",
      "QuestionType": "DropDown",
      "IsProfile": false,
      "IsRequired": false,
      "IsActive": false,
      "RegexExpression": "",
      "RequiredErrorText": "",
      "InvalidErrorText": "",
      "FieldName": "Q6",
      "FieldResponse": null,
      "OrderBy": 8,
      "CreatedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "ModifiedOn": null,
      "UserOptions": [
        {
          "Id": 10012,
          "Value": "Indtil 199.999 kr.",
          "Description": "Indtil 199.999 kr.",
          "Type": "Q6",
          "IsActive": false,
          "IsSelected": false,
          "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "OrderBy": 1,
          "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
        },
        {
          "Id": 10013,
          "Value": "200.000 - 399.999 kr.",
          "Description": "200.000 - 399.999 kr.",
          "Type": "Q6",
          "IsActive": false,
          "IsSelected": false,
          "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "OrderBy": 2,
          "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
        },
        {
          "Id": 10014,
          "Value": "400.000 - 749.999 kr.",
          "Description": "400.000 - 749.999 kr.",
          "Type": "Q6",
          "IsActive": false,
          "IsSelected": false,
          "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "OrderBy": 3,
          "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
        },
        {
          "Id": 10015,
          "Value": "750.000 - 999.999 kr.",
          "Description": "750.000 - 999.999 kr.",
          "Type": "Q6",
          "IsActive": false,
          "IsSelected": false,
          "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "OrderBy": 4,
          "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
        },
        {
          "Id": 10016,
          "Value": "1.000.000 kr. eller mere",
          "Description": "1.000.000 kr. eller mere",
          "Type": "Q6",
          "IsActive": false,
          "IsSelected": false,
          "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "OrderBy": 5,
          "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
        },
        {
          "Id": 10209,
          "Value": "Ønsker ikke at oplyse",
          "Description": "Ønsker ikke at oplyse",
          "Type": "Q6",
          "IsActive": false,
          "IsSelected": false,
          "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "OrderBy": 6,
          "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"AllowSecondClick": true,
"RemainingDays": 3668.0,
"ServiceUserStatus": "Completed",
"ShowQuarantineWarning": false,
"PartnerId": 0,
"SoldOutStatus": null
}
]
}
```

Comment: You don't need to export like this. Just put the data in file.json and import the data like
import jsonData from './filename'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access the array within the key `frontPage` of your JSON, but you're trying to map the whole JSON as if it is an array(but it's not).

You can do 2 approaches:

.either map the json object like `{this.state.data.frontPage.map()}`

.or fix your JSON to be exported as an array, and you won't need to change your mapping

```
export default [
  {
    "Id": "65f22db1-2a6c-4966-8c46-6ea6e02b5df3",
    "UserDataQuestions": [
      {
        "Id": 76,
        "EarnMoreServiceId": "65f22db1-2a6c-4966-8c46-6ea6e02b5df3",
        "QuestionText": "Adresse inkl. postnummer og by",
        "QuestionType": "TextBox",
        "IsProfile": false,
        "IsRequired": false,
        "IsActive": false,
        "RegexExpression": "",
        "RequiredErrorText": "",
        "InvalidErrorText": "",
        "FieldName": "FullAddress",
        "FieldResponse": null,
        "OrderBy": 4,
        "CreatedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ModifiedOn": null,
        "UserOptions": []
      },
      {
        "Id": 69,
        "EarnMoreServiceId": "65f22db1-2a6c-4966-8c46-6ea6e02b5df3",
        "QuestionText": "Har du hjemmeboende børn?",
        "QuestionType": "Radio",
        "IsProfile": false,
        "IsRequired": false,
        "IsActive": false,
        "RegexExpression": "",
        "RequiredErrorText": "",
        "InvalidErrorText": "",
        "FieldName": "field30",
        "FieldResponse": null,
        "OrderBy": 5,
        "CreatedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ModifiedOn": null,
        "UserOptions": [
          {
            "Id": 10608,
            "Value": "Ja",
            "Description": "Ja",
            "Type": "field30",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 1,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 69
          },
          {
            "Id": 10609,
            "Value": "Nej",
            "Description": "Nej",
            "Type": "field30",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 2,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 69
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": 68,
        "EarnMoreServiceId": "65f22db1-2a6c-4966-8c46-6ea6e02b5df3",
        "QuestionText": "Har du børn?",
        "QuestionType": "CheckBox",
        "IsProfile": false,
        "IsRequired": false,
        "IsActive": false,
        "RegexExpression": "",
        "RequiredErrorText": "",
        "InvalidErrorText": "",
        "FieldName": "Q68",
        "FieldResponse": null,
        "OrderBy": 7,
        "CreatedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ModifiedOn": null,
        "UserOptions": [
          {
            "Id": 10601,
            "Value": "Ingen børn",
            "Description": "Ingen børn",
            "Type": "Q68",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 1,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
          },
          {
            "Id": 10602,
            "Value": "Ja i alderen 0-3 år",
            "Description": "Ja i alderen 0-3 år",
            "Type": "Q68",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 2,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
          },
          {
            "Id": 10603,
            "Value": "Ja i alderen 4-6 år",
            "Description": "Ja i alderen 4-6 år",
            "Type": "Q68",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 3,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
          },
          {
            "Id": 10604,
            "Value": "Ja i alderen 7-9 år",
            "Description": "Ja i alderen 7-9 år",
            "Type": "Q68",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 4,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
          },
          {
            "Id": 10605,
            "Value": "Ja i alderen 10-13 år",
            "Description": "Ja i alderen 10-13 år",
            "Type": "Q68",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 5,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
          },
          {
            "Id": 10606,
            "Value": "Ja i alderen 14-18 år",
            "Description": "Ja i alderen 14-18 år",
            "Type": "Q68",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 6,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
          },
          {
            "Id": 10607,
            "Value": "Ja over 18 år.",
            "Description": "Ja over 18 år.",
            "Type": "Q68",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 7,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": 6,
        "EarnMoreServiceId": "65f22db1-2a6c-4966-8c46-6ea6e02b5df3",
        "QuestionText": "Indkomst (for hele din husstand, i alt pr. år før skat)",
        "QuestionType": "DropDown",
        "IsProfile": false,
        "IsRequired": false,
        "IsActive": false,
        "RegexExpression": "",
        "RequiredErrorText": "",
        "InvalidErrorText": "",
        "FieldName": "Q6",
        "FieldResponse": null,
        "OrderBy": 8,
        "CreatedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ModifiedOn": null,
        "UserOptions": [
          {
            "Id": 10012,
            "Value": "Indtil 199.999 kr.",
            "Description": "Indtil 199.999 kr.",
            "Type": "Q6",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 1,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
          },
          {
            "Id": 10013,
            "Value": "200.000 - 399.999 kr.",
            "Description": "200.000 - 399.999 kr.",
            "Type": "Q6",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 2,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
          },
          {
            "Id": 10014,
            "Value": "400.000 - 749.999 kr.",
            "Description": "400.000 - 749.999 kr.",
            "Type": "Q6",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 3,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
          },
          {
            "Id": 10015,
            "Value": "750.000 - 999.999 kr.",
            "Description": "750.000 - 999.999 kr.",
            "Type": "Q6",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 4,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
          },
          {
            "Id": 10016,
            "Value": "1.000.000 kr. eller mere",
            "Description": "1.000.000 kr. eller mere",
            "Type": "Q6",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 5,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
          },
          {
            "Id": 10209,
            "Value": "Ønsker ikke at oplyse",
            "Description": "Ønsker ikke at oplyse",
            "Type": "Q6",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 6,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "AllowSecondClick": true,
  "RemainingDays": 3668.0,
  "ServiceUserStatus": "Completed",
  "ShowQuarantineWarning": false,
  "PartnerId": 0,
  "SoldOutStatus": null,
]
```

-- EDIT --

Following the comments and see there is a requirement wheter question type should be displayed, It's not only access of JSON it's needed , it's the treatment of the data.

You need more treatment than just mapping your data.I recommend returning a render function to be able to do the correct return of what do you want. eg:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import frontPage from './dummy';

export default class DummyForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      field: '',
      checkBox: '',
      options: '',
      radioField: '',
      error: '',
      data: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: frontPage
    });
  }

  render_questions(element) {
    // to-do: treat your data here on the type of questions you want to render
    // If you want any, just return elm.UseDataQuestions
    const questionType = element.map(elm =>
      elm.UserDataQuestions.find(question => question === 'question')
    );
    return questionType.map(value => (
      <select className="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
        <option key={i}>{value.QuestionText}</option>
      </select>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    console.log(frontPage);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>{this.state.data.map((x, i) => this.render_questions(x))}</React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i get data from UserDataQuestions array.?

Comment: Once you map your first array. than you can access the UserDataQuestions within the map , eg.: `let userQuestions = this.state.data.frontPage.map( value => value.UserDataQuestions)` . or if you want to map on render `{this.state.data.map((x, i) => x.UserDataQuestions.map( questions => 
                (<select className="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
                  <option key={i}>
                    {questions.QuestionText}
                  </option>
                </select>
              ))))}`

Comment: I have a scenario that what ever `QuestionType` in the json file is the question should be displayed according ly

Comment: I've added more information on my answer, I hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried it is giving an error `this.state.map` is not a function

Comment: Have you tried to console.log `frontpage` to see if your import is correct? You have to check that, you won't be able to map if your data is null when you set the value of data === JSON on componentdidmount. And I've changed the constructor, where actually you have to initiate your data as an empty array, otherwise, it will be null when you first render your page. Now, I don't think I can help you more than that. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Change your data file to:

```js
export default [
  {
    "Id": "65f22db1-2a6c-4966-8c46-6ea6e02b5df3",
    "UserDataQuestions": [
      {
        "Id": 76,
        "EarnMoreServiceId": "65f22db1-2a6c-4966-8c46-6ea6e02b5df3",
        "QuestionText": "Adresse inkl. postnummer og by",
        "QuestionType": "TextBox",
        "IsProfile": false,
        "IsRequired": false,
        "IsActive": false,
        "RegexExpression": "",
        "RequiredErrorText": "",
        "InvalidErrorText": "",
        "FieldName": "FullAddress",
        "FieldResponse": null,
        "OrderBy": 4,
        "CreatedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ModifiedOn": null,
        "UserOptions": []
      },
      {
        "Id": 69,
        "EarnMoreServiceId": "65f22db1-2a6c-4966-8c46-6ea6e02b5df3",
        "QuestionText": "Har du hjemmeboende børn?",
        "QuestionType": "Radio",
        "IsProfile": false,
        "IsRequired": false,
        "IsActive": false,
        "RegexExpression": "",
        "RequiredErrorText": "",
        "InvalidErrorText": "",
        "FieldName": "field30",
        "FieldResponse": null,
        "OrderBy": 5,
        "CreatedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ModifiedOn": null,
        "UserOptions": [
          {
            "Id": 10608,
            "Value": "Ja",
            "Description": "Ja",
            "Type": "field30",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 1,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 69
          },
          {
            "Id": 10609,
            "Value": "Nej",
            "Description": "Nej",
            "Type": "field30",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 2,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 69
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": 68,
        "EarnMoreServiceId": "65f22db1-2a6c-4966-8c46-6ea6e02b5df3",
        "QuestionText": "Har du børn?",
        "QuestionType": "CheckBox",
        "IsProfile": false,
        "IsRequired": false,
        "IsActive": false,
        "RegexExpression": "",
        "RequiredErrorText": "",
        "InvalidErrorText": "",
        "FieldName": "Q68",
        "FieldResponse": null,
        "OrderBy": 7,
        "CreatedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ModifiedOn": null,
        "UserOptions": [
          {
            "Id": 10601,
            "Value": "Ingen børn",
            "Description": "Ingen børn",
            "Type": "Q68",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 1,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
          },
          {
            "Id": 10602,
            "Value": "Ja i alderen 0-3 år",
            "Description": "Ja i alderen 0-3 år",
            "Type": "Q68",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 2,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
          },
          {
            "Id": 10603,
            "Value": "Ja i alderen 4-6 år",
            "Description": "Ja i alderen 4-6 år",
            "Type": "Q68",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 3,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
          },
          {
            "Id": 10604,
            "Value": "Ja i alderen 7-9 år",
            "Description": "Ja i alderen 7-9 år",
            "Type": "Q68",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 4,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
          },
          {
            "Id": 10605,
            "Value": "Ja i alderen 10-13 år",
            "Description": "Ja i alderen 10-13 år",
            "Type": "Q68",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 5,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
          },
          {
            "Id": 10606,
            "Value": "Ja i alderen 14-18 år",
            "Description": "Ja i alderen 14-18 år",
            "Type": "Q68",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 6,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
          },
          {
            "Id": 10607,
            "Value": "Ja over 18 år.",
            "Description": "Ja over 18 år.",
            "Type": "Q68",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 7,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 68
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": 6,
        "EarnMoreServiceId": "65f22db1-2a6c-4966-8c46-6ea6e02b5df3",
        "QuestionText": "Indkomst (for hele din husstand, i alt pr. år før skat)",
        "QuestionType": "DropDown",
        "IsProfile": false,
        "IsRequired": false,
        "IsActive": false,
        "RegexExpression": "",
        "RequiredErrorText": "",
        "InvalidErrorText": "",
        "FieldName": "Q6",
        "FieldResponse": null,
        "OrderBy": 8,
        "CreatedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ModifiedOn": null,
        "UserOptions": [
          {
            "Id": 10012,
            "Value": "Indtil 199.999 kr.",
            "Description": "Indtil 199.999 kr.",
            "Type": "Q6",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 1,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
          },
          {
            "Id": 10013,
            "Value": "200.000 - 399.999 kr.",
            "Description": "200.000 - 399.999 kr.",
            "Type": "Q6",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 2,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
          },
          {
            "Id": 10014,
            "Value": "400.000 - 749.999 kr.",
            "Description": "400.000 - 749.999 kr.",
            "Type": "Q6",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 3,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
          },
          {
            "Id": 10015,
            "Value": "750.000 - 999.999 kr.",
            "Description": "750.000 - 999.999 kr.",
            "Type": "Q6",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 4,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
          },
          {
            "Id": 10016,
            "Value": "1.000.000 kr. eller mere",
            "Description": "1.000.000 kr. eller mere",
            "Type": "Q6",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 5,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
          },
          {
            "Id": 10209,
            "Value": "Ønsker ikke at oplyse",
            "Description": "Ønsker ikke at oplyse",
            "Type": "Q6",
            "IsActive": false,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "ModifiedOn": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "OrderBy": 6,
            "EarnMoreServiceQuestionId": 6
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "AllowSecondClick": true,
  "RemainingDays": 3668.0,
  "ServiceUserStatus": "Completed",
  "ShowQuarantineWarning": false,
  "PartnerId": 0,
  "SoldOutStatus": null,
]
```

Comment: how can i get data from UserDataQuestions array @Jack